# Make one flex item occupy the entire column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

I have an unordered list in a flex layout. I want the first `li` item (which is the "home" link of a menu) to be positioned in its own column like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

---

Due to semantics I don't want to break out the first list item and put it in a separate div. I want it to be in the list in the HTML.

```css
* {
  outline: solid 1px grey;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
}

ul > li:first-child {
  /* This item should be in its own column */
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    First item and this is it
  </li>
  <li>
    Second item this is the sh*t
  </li>
  <li>
    Third after two to go
  </li>
  <li>
    Forth enabled flex is flow
  </li>
  <li>
    Fifth the rabbit digs a hole
  </li>
  <li>
    Sixth hole in the pork says "miew"
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://codepen.io/rooeee/pen/ObZwER

Answer (score 2):

In a flex container with `row wrap` there's really no way to achieve this layout, unless you add containers. I understand you prefer not to change the HTML.

However, if you can switch to `column wrap` and define a height for the container, then you can make the first link occupy the whole column by giving it `flex-basis: 100%`. This forces subsequent items to wrap.

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmxEmQ)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100px;
}
li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
ul > li:first-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  color: green;
}
* {
  outline: solid 1px grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    First item and this is it
  </li>
  <li>
    Second item this is the sh*t
  </li>
  <li>
    Third after two to go
  </li>
  <li>
    Forth enabled flex is flow
  </li>
  <li>
    Fifth the rabbit digs a hole
  </li>
  <li>
    Sixth hole in the pork says "miew"
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**ALSO**, if your only reason for not wanting to alter the HTML is semantics, you can still build the layout in a row-based container while adhering to clean, valid and semantic code. In other words, creating nested flex containers is fine.

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVjwqv)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
ul:first-child > li:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
ul:first-child > li:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
}
ul:first-child > li:nth-child(2) ul {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul:first-child > li:nth-child(2) li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  outline: solid 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<ul><!-- primary flex container -->
  <li>First item and this is it</li><!-- flex item #1 -->
  <li><!-- flex item #2 -->
    <ul><!-- nested flex container -->
      <li>Second item this is the sh*t</li><!-- flex item -->
      <li>Third after two to go</li><!-- flex item -->
      <li>Forth enabled flex is flow</li><!-- flex item -->
      <li>Fifth the rabbit digs a hole</li><!-- flex item -->
      <li>Sixth hole in the pork says "miew</li><!-- flex item -->
    </ul><!-- END nested flex container -->
  </li><!-- END flex item #2 -->
</ul><!-- END primary flex container -->
```

Comment: Nice suggestion! For your information: I could change the html, as long as it is sematic. I don't want to move the first list item outside of the html list, but I could enclose it in a div if that would help to achieve this in a row based layout.

Comment: Okay, I revised my answer. See new example at bottom.

Comment: Thanks, looks very good. But don't you think moving second item and onwards and put them in a sub-ordered list is changing the meaning of the list?

Comment: Everything is still in one overall list. I don't see anything wrong with this structure in terms of semantics. However, if you have doubts, use the column layout.